# C++ Class - std::vector class variable resets after function

Tags: c++, oop, stdvector

I'm just getting back into c++ programming and running into an issue. I have a class containing an std::vector as follows:

```
class node{

  private:
    std::string name;
    node* parent;
    std::vector<node*> children;

  public:
    node();
    ~node();
    //Setters
    void setName(std::string nodeName);
    void setParent(node* &newParent);
    void addChild(node* child);
    //Getters
    std::string getName();
    node* getParent();
    std::vector<node*> getChildren();
    node* getChild(unsigned index);
};
```

Relevant member functions are implemented as follows:

```
void node::addChild(node* child){
  children.push_back(child);
  if(children.size() == 2){
    children.erase(children.begin());
  }
}

void node::setParent(node* &newParent){
  parent = newParent;
  if(parent != NULL){
    parent->addChild(this);
  }
}

node* node::getParent(){
  return parent;
}

std::vector<node*> node::getChildren(){
  return children;
}
```

In another file, I've got a function doing this:

```
void loadTree(std::ifstream &datafile, tree &hierarchicalModel){
    node root();
    node child = readNode(datafile, root);
    root.addChild(&child);
    hierarchicalModel.addRoot(root);
    //I hard coded this in to test, and it prints out exactly what I want.
    std::cout<<hierarchicalModel.getRoot().getChildren()[0]->getName()<<std::endl;
}
```

This issue is here: in my main file, I do this (hierarchicalModel is declared as a global variable):

```
void setup(){
    loadTree(dataFile, hierarchicalModel);
    //This will print out exactly what I expect.
    std::cout<<hierachicalModel.getRoot()->getName()<<std::endl;
    //Here is the issue!
    //I hard coded this as well, and it causes a crash. 
    std::cout<<hierarchicalModel.getRoot().getChildren()[0]->getName()<<std::endl;
}
```

I cannot access the children outside of the scope of the function where I added them. I thought that passing the tree object by reference would handle this.

Please help!! And let me know if answering this question requires more information!!

Comment: The shown code samples fail to meet the requirements for a [mcve], and as such it's unlikely that you will get your answer. You need to edit your question, and provide a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: `node root();` declares a function taking no parameters and returning `node` - not a variable of type `node`.

Comment: Assuming that the `tree::getRoot` function returns by value, and that `node::getChildren` does as well, you have a lot of copying happening. It might also be the root of your problem, since you don't seem to follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: `root.addChild(&child);` stores a pointer to a local variable into the tree. As soon as the function returns, `child` is destroyed and the pointer becomes dangling. Your program very likely triggers undefined behavior shortly thereafter, when it attempts to actually use that pointer.

Comment: ^^ Thank you! I think this is the issue